# How to use enter to move cursor to next textbox instead of submit?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gJyT.png)   I'm trying to move the cursor to the next textbox by pressing `Enter`.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="bondtapelbl" runat="server" Text="Bond Tape :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial Black" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                </strong>
                <asp:TextBox ID="bondtape" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" Height="35px" Font-Size="Medium" Width="130px" CssClass="bt" />

                &nbsp;<span class="auto-style6">&amp;</span><strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="productranklbl" runat="server" Text="Product Rank :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial Black" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="productrank" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" Height="35px" Font-Size="Medium" Width="130px" CssClass="pr" />

                    <asp:Button ID="bontapeButton" Text="Search" runat="server" BackColor="#3399FF" BorderStyle="None" CssClass="btsearch" ForeColor="White" Height="39px" Width="80px" />
                </strong></td>
```

I'm using javascript for this. The problem is that instead of moving the cursor to the next text box, it automatically execute the search button.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

                //Bind keyup event to textbox
                $('btsearch[type="bondtape"]').keyup(function (event) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        $("pr").next().focus();
                    }
                });

            </script>
```

My javascript is based on this answer that I got from the other forum:

```
$('input[type="textbox"]').keyup(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).next().focus();
}});
```

I've only learnt javascript for 2/3 days so I don't really know in which part I'm wrong. I would be grateful if anyone could help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do this? The tab key already does this for free, and that's what users expect.

Comment: thanks for the response @nnnnnn .this is actually part of my internship project. I'm using this method because that is what previous programmer do with the code and I'm just trying to avoid too much of modification on the code. May I ask ..is this method wrong  or the tab key method supposed to be a better approach?

Comment: Well the concept of the tab key moving to the next field is something that pretty much all desktop browsers implement by default. And shift+tab moves to the previous field. (Most desktop applications do some variation of this too.) It is standard behaviour that users expect, so there's not really a need to apply the same thing to the Enter key.

Comment: okay thanks, but I'm using a scanner for this particular input instead of typing it in. So I'm afraid that using the tab key method may not suitable for it (since my supervisor said so ) or is it ? @nnnnnn

Comment: Sure, well if you have a special case like that then just do whatever makes it easiest for the user. Regarding your actual problem, you may need to add `e.preventDefault()` in your keyup handler. And you may need to use a key *down* handler rather than key *up* (not sure about that). You need to include your script after the elements in question, and/or put your code inside a `$(document).ready()` handler.

Comment: `$("pr")` will look for a `<pr>` element, which you don't have. And `.next()` only selects the next *immediately adjacent sibling* element, so if the next input is in a separate `<td>` you will need to do something like `$(this).closest("td").next().find("input.pr").focus();` - or `...closest("tr")...` if there is one input per row. I'd need to see a sample of your html for at least two rows to be more specific about this part.

Comment: hi @nnnnnn ,I've already add the screenshot example on my question above.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607333/by-pressing-enter-key-move-to-next-textbox-in-asp-net?rq=1
I'd suggest you follow a combination of what @nnnnnn and the link I posted suggests - include your script in the correct part of the page, use `e.preventDefault();` , only bind the function of the keydown event of your first textbox (unless your sample was incomplete), and make sure you're setting the focus to the correct element (using something like @nnnnnn's example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay I just want to share the answer that I got. Here is the link that I got my answer from(you can also try the demo) :  http://www.latentmotion.com/downloads/enter-to-tab.html
and below is the javascript that work with my project. The solution that I got is I replaced my javascript on the question with the javascript below. I hope this could help other people .

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").not( $(":button") ).keypress(function (evt) {
            if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                iname = $(this).val();
                if (iname !== 'Submit'){    
                    var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find('button,input,textarea,select');
                    var index = fields.index( this );
                    if ( index > -1 && ( index + 1 ) < fields.length ) {
                        fields.eq( index + 1 ).focus();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```